# How to test if a c-string contains characters outside certain ascii range?

Tags: c

So, let say I have simple code below:

```
int main() {
    char string1[256]="TEST1";
    char string2[256]="TESTOK"; //Also could be "TEST OK"

    if(//string doesn't contain "A-Z" || doesn't contain "SPACE")
    {
        //do something
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Where the if statement is, all I would want to do is have string1 go into the if statement, because it contains something other than ASCII characters A-Z or a SPACE. However, in both examples of string2, I would want them to bypass the if statement because it contains A-Z or may have a SPACE, which all would be ok and should mean the char string doesn't go into the if statement.

I can not find a simple way to do this with c, to test for this. I have considered just looping through all the characters and testing if the ASCII value is of a certain value range or equals 32 for the space. However, that seems overly complicated. Also, I purposely set the 256 larger than the amount of characters in the string, so I worry about NULL characters messing things up possibly too.

Anyways, is there a simple way to do a test like this in C? Thanks for any help.

Comment: The pseudo code in your "if" does not match your description, phrased as it is, neither string1 nor string2 should go to "then", because both do contain at least one of A-Z. Description would have string one in "then", because string1 "contains something which is neither A-Z nor space".

Comment: Please explore the library functions `strspn` and `strcspn`.

Comment: Ok, I would edit the post but it will not allow me to edit the post. Either way, my question is if c has a built in basic function to do this instead of having to do all this manually.

Comment: Didn't you read my previous comment?

Comment: @Weather Vane, thanks for your response. You were the one to actually answer my questions. Thanks, those are exactly what I was looking for. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Moreover if you want an iterative solution there is a family of library functions such as `isalpha` and `isupper` etc.

Comment: @Weather Vane, thanks for that idea as well. All great solutions that I can work with, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`strspn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strspn.html) (or `strcspn()`), prototype in `<string.h>`

```
char okchar[] = "ABC...Z 0123456789";
if (strspn(input, okchar) == strlen(input)) /* ok */;
```

Comment: I did not know about `strspn()`. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think iterating over the characters would be too complicated:

```
int i = 0;
while (string1[i] != '\0') {
    if (!((string[i] >= 'A' && string[i] <= 'Z') || string[i] == ' ')) {
        printf("Not good\n");
        break;
    }
    ++i;
}
```

**EDIT:**

As Stargateur commented, using `isupper` would be more elegant:

```
int i = 0;
while (string1[i] != '\0') {
    if (!(isupper(string[i]) || string[i] == ' ')) {
        printf("Not good\n");
        break;
    }
    ++i;
}
```

Comment: Should `string[]` contain a negative value (and not `EOF`), `isupper()` is UB.  Could use `isupper((unsigned char) string[i])`   `isupper()` can return true for values other than `'A'-'Z'`, depending on _locale_, although most programs only use the C locale.  `(string[i] >= 'A' && string[i] <= 'Z') || string[i] == ' '` does not have these problems.

Answer (score 1):

> ASCII characters A-Z or a SPACE.

Source code's encoding may not be [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) - this is rare, yet serves as an opportunity to distinguish between source code, say in [EBCIDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) encoding and the contents of a string, read from external input, which is to be interpreted as ASCII data.

Note: regardless of encoding, the *null character* has the value `'\0'`.

This is a time when code *should* use 32, 65 and 90.  `#define ASCII_A 'A'` does  not work because the `'A'` is interpreted in the source code's encoding, which may differ from ASCII.

```
#define ASCII_SPACE 32
#define ASCII_A 65
#define ASCII_Z 90
```

Also no need to test for the *null character* in the loop.

```
// return true if `s` contains only ASCII A-Z or space and then the null character
bool test_ASCII_AZ_space(const char *s) {
  while ((*s >= ASCII_A && *s <= ASCII_Z) || (*s == ASCII_SPACE)) {
    s++;
  }
  return *s == '\0';
}
```

To employ portability this using `strspn()` as suggested by [@pmg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44348019/2410359) requires that the pattern string is formed using ASCII values.  Also no need to use `strlen()` to run down the string again, just check if the value returned by `strspn()` indexes to the *null character*.

```
const char okchar[] = { 32, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69,
  70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79,
  80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, '\0' };

if (input[strspn(input, okchar)] == '\0') {
  /* ok */;
}
```